# ListView doesn't refresh after using changeCursor() on its adapter

Tags: android, cursor, android-listview, android-fragments, android-cursoradapter

I'm using a database, and there's a list fragment which use a cursor adapter to I get by querying the databse in a loader.
When the user press a list view item long press, he sees a context menu and a option to delete this entry.
When he press delete I'm starting a thread that deletes this entry and then start the loader again to get a new cursor (becuase "requery()" is deprecated).
When the loader finishes to load the new cursor I'm trying to use `changeCursor` method that suppose to refresh the list view but it doesn't do it, so I tried using `notifyDataSetChanged` but it doesn't work too.
I've checked and the cursor coming back from the loader and it does change the cursor but the list view doesn't refresh.

What should I do? Restart the fragment?

Here's some code:

```
case MENU_REMOVE:
            final AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
            mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), getString(R.string.list_remove_progress_title_text),
                    getString(R.string.progress_dialog_description));
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    PlacesHandler wph = new PlacesHandler(getActivity());
                    wph.DeleteEntry(mPlaceName, info.id);
                    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, ListFragment.this);
                }
            }).start();
            return(true);
```

When finished loading:

```
@Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        if(mProgress == null || !mProgress.isShowing()){
            ...
        }
        else{
            mProgress.dismiss();
            mAdapter.changeCursor(data);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you calling `cursor.requery()` to refresh your cursor?

Comment: No, cursor.requery() is working but it's deprecated, so I'm using changeCursor() because this is what was written in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everyone but I found my problem!
The cursor that was returned from the loader was the same cursor as what was in the adapter.
This is because I called:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

instead of:

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
```

So because I've already used the loader with the ID 0 when I first loaded the cursor when the fragment was created, it just returned me the cursor immediately. 
So if some people face the same problem and read it, just know that `initLoader` uses an existing loader with the specified ID if there is one. If there isn't, it creates one.
But if you want to discard the loader's old data and start over you should use `restartLoader`.

Again, thanks for anyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 1):

After deleting a SQLite register, I simply did this:

> myAdapter.getFilter().filter("");

Comment: that's the solution for me, but I didn't specify any filter ... why android, just why

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things. I'm not familiar with fragments, so I'll just try to help you out.

Where are you updating the cursor to fetch the new data? Also, try using an AsyncTask to do the deleting. When done, update the adapter in the postexecute method.

Comment: The deleting itself made in a thread as you can see. This is not so complicated task so I prefered doing it on a thread instead of implementing AsyncTask. The loading of the new cursor is being made with a loader that it's kind of AsyncTask. The `onLoadFinished` callback is like postexecute of AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the similar problem by creating new curson and new adapter. And then setting new adapter to the list view:
`myListView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);`

The ony problem of this approach is that my list view doesn't keep scroll position.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, can you please add here your code so I will see exactly how you did it?